# Finding out the changes in a github release

Tags: git, github

I have this thought confusing me a lot. Please correct me if I am wrong:

Assume there is a github repo named project123. The repo has over 50 releases and currently on release 53. My local cloned repo is on say release 17(very old). I have been tasked to upgrade the local project by customizing our own changes as we jump to every release one by one. How do I achieve this?

Here is how I am thinking:

Currently on release 23. Download the release 24 .zip from the official project123 github repo. Make some changes. Commit and push to my personal repo. Is this the right way?

How do I find what changed in release 24?

Comment: I think you are beginner in git. Try read some git documentation. Try to watch git workflow video tutorial.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide)

Comment: No, that's not the right way. To update your local repo from remote you need to pull commits from it, not just update files.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working in a terminal, using the Github Desktop Interface, or looking at things through the web interface? [Github Help](https://help.github.com/) has a [commits](https://help.github.com/categories/commits/) section, and you'll probably be interested in the [Comparing commits across time](https://help.github.com/articles/comparing-commits-across-time/) section of it. Also, using the online interface, under the **Commits** page of a repository, there is a tab labeled **History** where you can see all the commits for the repository that you're under. I suspect this is what you are looking for.